# WPF Buttonstyle not properly drawn using Window.Shapes.Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, wpf-style

I am currently learning WPF with MVVM pattern and I have a 'weird' behaviour, when I am drawing a button using Windows.Shapes.Path.

Doing some testing I narrowed the issue down to pure WPF. Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonStyleTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonStyleTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Path Data="M1,9 L9,1 M1,1 L9,9" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0"  >
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1"  >
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images, since I need 10 reputation :(
So I just post the links - sorry for the inconvenience.

The running program looks like this
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8541/HBAHyi.png

After I resize my window, the buttons are drawn differently
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/4600/gzEXWj.png

If I use the string "X" as content, i.e.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="x"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

every button gets its "x".

In my real application I found a workaround. The buttons are bound to a ObservableCollection. If I specify the `<Path Data... />` Tag within a Datatemplate everything is shown correctly. When defining it as a button style it looks like above.

However, I want to understand WHY the path property is not working for me within a style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your style so it looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" x:Shared="False" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Path Data="M1,9 L9,1 M1,1 L9,9" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then it will work the way you want it.

Here is some details about [x:Shared Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically what it does is that it creates a new instance of the style when it is set to `FALSE`. And you need to create a new instance of `PATH` for each button.